# How to apply pv.uneven (FinCal library) (or any function with vectors as input) to every row of a data frame?

Tags: r, function, apply

I'm trying to do a Present Value on every row of a dataframe, this shouldn't be too hard, but in each row it has to use a specific range of columns. I have this:

```
int<-sample(0:3,1000,rep=TRUE)/100
period<-sample(1:9,1000,rep=TRUE)
a<-data.frame(replicate(10,sample(0:10,1000,rep=TRUE)),int,period)
```

Suppose that columns 1:10 are the payments, then there is the interest rate for the PV and the last column (period) indicates from which column starts the PV for that particular row. I'm using a `for` to accomplish this, but I'm wondering if there is an easier way, since I'm doing it on a dataframe with over 1 million rows:

```
a$vpn<-0
for (i in 1:nrow(a))
{
a$vpn[i]<-pv.uneven(a$int[i],a[i,a$period[i]:10])

}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We don't know what `pv.uneven` is, but suppose we have

```
pv<-function(interest,cfs) sum(cfs*(1+interest)^-seq_along(cfs))
```

so that for a given row `i` of data frame `a`, you want `pv(a$int[i],a[i,a$period[i]:10])`.

A useful trick then is to create an auxillary function

```
pv.aux<-function(int,period,end=10,...) pv(int,c(...)[period:end])
```

So that you can just `do.call` an `mapply`

```
a$vpn<-do.call(mapply,c(pv.aux,a))
```

For me this is many times faster than your current loop solution.

Comment: ...where many times faster is approximately 50x speedup for this sample data